# Should enum instances be compared by identity or equality?

Tags: python, enums

PEP 8 [Programming Recommendations](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations) says:

> Comparisons to singletons like None should always be done with `is` or `is not`, never the equality operators.

According to the docs, [enum members are singletons](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html?highlight=enum#enum-members-aka-instances). Does that mean they should also be compared by identity?

```
class Color(Enum):
    RED = 1
    GREEN = 2
    BLUE = 3

# like this?
if color is Color.RED:
    ...

# or like this
if color == Color.RED:
    ...
```

When using equality operators, I haven't noticed any issues with this to warrant such strong wording as PEP 8. What's the drawback of using equality, if any? Doesn't it just fall back to an identity-based comparison anyway? Is this just a micro-optimisation?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

From https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#module-enum:

> Within an enumeration, the members can be compared by identity

In particular, from https://docs.python.org/3/howto/enum.html#comparisons :

> Enumeration members are compared by identity

and

> Equality comparisons are defined though

Answer (score 10):

First, we can definitely rule out `x.value is y.value`, because those aren't singletons, those are perfectly ordinary values that you've stored in attributes.

But what about `x is y`?

First, I believe that, by "singletons like None", PEP 8 is specifically referring to the small, fixed set of built-in singletons that are like `None` in some important way. What important way? Why do you want to compare `None` with `is`?

Readability: `if foo is None:` reads like what it means. On the rare occasions when you want to distinguish `True` from other truthy values, `if spam is True:` reads better than `if spam == True:`, as well as making it more obvious that this isn't just a frivolous `== True` used by someone improperly following a C++ coding standard in Python. That might apply in `foo is Potato.spud`, but not so much in `x is y`.

Use as a sentinel: `None` is used to mean "value missing" or "search failed" or similar cases. It shouldn't be used in cases where `None` itself can be a value, of course. And if someone creates a class whose instances compare equal to `None`, it's possible to run into that problem without realizing it. `is None` protects against that. This is even more of a problem with `True` and `False` (again, on those rare occasions when you want to distinguish them), since `1 == True` and `0 == False`. This reason doesn't seem to apply here—if `1 == Potato.spud`, that's only because you intentionally chose to use an `IntEnum` instead of an `Enum`, in which case that's exactly what you want…

(Quasi-)keyword status: `None` and friends have gradually migrated from perfectly normal builtin to keyword over the years. Not only is the default value of the symbol `None` always going to be the singleton, the only *possible* value is that singleton. This means that an optimizer, static linter, etc. can make an assumption about what `None` means in your code, in a way that it can't for anything defined at runtime. Again, this reason doesn't seem to apply.

Performance: This really is not a consideration at all. It might be faster, on some implementations, to compare with `is` than with `==`, but this is incredibly unlikely to ever make a difference in real code (or, if it does, that real code probably needs a higher-level optimization, like turning a list into a set…).

So, what's the conclusion?

Well, it's hard to get away from an opinion here, but I think it's reasonable to say that:

- `if devo is Potato.spud:` is reasonable if it makes things more readable, but as long as you're consistent within a code base, I don't think anyone will complain either way.
- `if x is y:`, even when they're both known to be `Potato` objects, is not reasonable.
- `if x.value is Potato.spud.value` is not reasonable.

Comment: `if spam is True` also avoids the pitfall of `True == 1`.

Comment: @user2357112 When would that ever come up?

Comment: @Veedrac: Not often, but we're already assuming we're in the situation of needing to distinguish `True` from other values considered true in a boolean context. It's not much of a stretch for those other values to be numeric. Maybe in situations like implementing some sort of generic JSON processing thing, where you need to handle booleans and numbers differently, it might be important.

Comment: @user2357112: Agreed—in fact, I suspect distinguishing `True` from `1` might not just be a plausible scenario for testing `True` vs. other truthy values, but maybe the most common, maybe even most common by far. (For `False`, of course, there's always testing vs. `None`, but that's probably more clearly written as `if foo is not None: … elif not foo:` than an explicit `False` test.)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html?highlight=enum#comparisons  seems to contradict your claim "if x is y:, even when they're both known to be Potato objects, is not reasonable".  this may be a recent addition to the docs because I didn't notice it before ...

Comment: @wim: What about that contradicts my claim? The docs show that `Potato.spud is Potato.spud` is reasonable, which I think is completely uncontroversial. My claim is that `devo is Potato.spud` is also often reasonable, but `devo is jerry` is likely to be confusing unless it's directly visible that they're both `Potato` objects (even if you can prove that they must be). And `devo == jerry` is sufficient to exclude the case where `jerry` is actually `Potato.spud.value` with `Enum` and include it with `IntEnum`, which is exactly what you want in both cases.

Answer (score 9):

PEP 8 says:

> Comparisons to singletons like None should always be done with `is` or `is not`, never the equality operators.

I disagree with abarnert: the reason for this isn't because these are built-in or *special* in any way. It's because in these cases you care about having *the* object, not something that looks like it.

When using `is None`, for example, you care about whether it's **the `None`** that you put there, not a different `None` that had been passed in. This might be difficult in practice (there is only one `None`, after all) but it does sometimes matter.

Take, for example:

```
no_argument = object()
def foo(x=no_argument):
    if x OP no_argument:
        ...
    ...
```

If `OP` is `is`, this is perfectly idiomatic code. If it's `==`, it's not.

For the same reason, you should make the decision as so:

- If you want equality to duck type, such as with `IntEnum` or an Enum that you might want to subclass and overwrite (such as when you have complex enum types with methods and other extras) it makes sense to use `==`.
- When you are using enums as dumb sentinels, use `is`.

Comment: I conclude that `if devo is Potato.spud:` is reasonable (although people probably won't complain if you avoid it), and you conclude that `if X is no_argument:` is perfectly idiomatic. I list 4 cases where `is` may be appropriate, dismissing only the last one, and you say there's more than 1 reason why `is` is appropriate, listing one of the same ones I already listed. So… what are you disagreeing with here?

Comment: You write 'First, I believe that, by "singletons like None", PEP 8 is specifically referring to the small, fixed set of built-in singletons that are like None in some important way.' That's what I was referring to in the part mentioning you.

Comment: I also disagree with '`if x is y:`, even when they're both known to be `Potato` objects, is not reasonable.' Using `is` here is much clearer about the intent.

Comment: For the first one: it's pretty clear what Barry had in mind when he wrote PEP 8. The question is not how to dig for a direct answer where one doesn't exist, but to figure out how to extend the spirit of the answer to fit modern Python. The fact that it's clearly idiomatic to check `if foo is sentinel:` after `sentinel = object()`, despite that not being said anywhere in PEP 8, is in the same direction as `if foo is Enum.constant:`, and about the same distance, so it's a pretty obvious extension.

Comment: Meanwhile, for `if x is y:`, it's very rare that you're going to be comparing things that are provably both enum values but not obviously from immediate context. But when it comes up, I think doing so would hurt readability. Someone has to figure out that you're doing this because `x` and `y` both have to be enum values of the same type, then figure out why and where they come from, to understand your code. That seems like you're sending them off in the wrong direction.

Comment: I'll agree that cases like `y = Potato.spud if spam else Potato.idaho` immediately followed by `if x is y:` are a different story. In that case, it _is_ more readable with `is`.

Comment: @abarnert I'm not convinced; using `is` pretty much says "I'm comparing sentinels", that seems like exactly the right direction to send them off on.